# Excel 2007 Add-in in Ribbon doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba, add-in, ribbon

I saw some code posted by Username Rory and wanted to edit it so that I can run my macro from the add-in in ribbon. After I pasted them all in the ThisWorkBook module it does add the ribbon button there but every time I click on it I get:

> The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled"

I am pretty sure I had the enable all macros option on from Excel options. Below are the codes, all under "ThisWorkBook":

```
Private Const Button As String = "SomeName"

Sub Auto_Open()
  Dim CmdBar As CommandBar
  Dim CmdBarMenu As CommandBarControl
  Dim CmdBarMenuItem As CommandBarControl

  Set CmdBar = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar")
  Set CmdBarMenu = CmdBar.Controls("Tools")   ' Index 6

On Error Resume Next
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     CmdBarMenu.Controls(Button).Delete
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0

Set CmdBarMenuItem = CmdBarMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
With CmdBarMenuItem
   .Caption = Button
   .OnAction = "Hello"
End With

End Sub

Sub Auto_Close()
Dim CmdBar As CommandBar
Dim CmdBarMenu As CommandBarControl

Set CmdBar = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar")
Set CmdBarMenu = CmdBar.Controls("Tools")   ' Index 6

On Error Resume Next
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     CmdBarMenu.Controls(Button).Delete
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub

Sub Hello()
MsgBox ("Hello")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the code here that's giving you the error the '.onAction' as seen below:

```
With CmdBarMenuItem
   .Caption = Button
   .OnAction = "Hello"
End With
```

The idea here is you need to reprogram the "Hello" to a macro. Right now its looking for a subroutine called 'Hello', and it cannot find it. If you're putting all your code in 'ThisWorkbook', I'd suggest denoting that here as well to make it more strongly typed. Here is an example if you want the button to call a routine called 'MyClick_Event' that you created in ThisWorkbook:

```
With CmdBarMenuItem
   .Caption = Button
   .OnAction = "ThisWorkbook.MyClick_Event"
End With
```

You can also create calls from other VBA sheets such as:

```
With CmdBarMenuItem
   .Caption = Button
   .OnAction = "Sheet1.MyClick_Event"
End With
```

Comment: May I ask another question-what should I do if I am to place it in a module? No I am having a problem that when I run the add in on some other spreadsheet it still refers to the value on the spreadsheet that I build the add in from. I changed the action to an event that would use some values on the spreadsheet.